# Запятая в предложении на белорусском языке

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Почему в этом предложении ставиться запятая?
**Сонная, яна хистанулася на нагах и шпарка пайшла у хату.**

Comment: Редактирование вопроса. Почему ставится запятая?  Почему  ставится запятая в следующем предложении: Сонная, она качнулась на ногах и быстро пошла в хату (перевод желательно проверить). ПОЯСНЕНИЕ к редактированию..  Белорусская пунктуация во многом идентична русской, хотя имеются некоторые отличия.http://elib.bsu.by/bitstream/123456789/12943/1/ОБУЧЕНИЕ%20ПУНКТУАЦИИ%20С%20УЧЁТОМ%20РАЗЛИЧИЙ%20В%20НОВЫХ%20РЕДАКЦИЯХ%20ПРАВИЛ%20БЕЛОРУССКОЙ%20И%20РУССКОЙ%20ПУНКТУАЦИИ.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Определение обособлено, т.к. имеет дополнительное обстоятельственное значение (причина): так как была сонная, будучи сонной.

Answer (score 2):

**Сонная, яна хистанулася на нагах и шпарка пайшла у хату.**

Обстоятельственное значение здесь, конечно, присутствует, но основной причиной обособления является то, что **яна (= она) ― это местоимение.**

Определения, отнесенные к местоимению, обособляются в обязательном порядке, так как они грамматически не сочетаются с местоимениями.